# Custom UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

I created a subclass of UIImageView to pass some strings from and to it. I also created a custom class of UITableViewCell and put four of my *UIStringImageView* inside of it.

I did this for a gallery like thumbnail tableView.
Then I added an UITapGestureRecognizer to every single UIStringImageView to open the corresponding image.

Now I want to add an overlay onto the UIStringImageView (with opacity) ti indicate touches on the single imageViews.

Here my code (from the UIStringImageView's implementation):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    [overlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5]];
    [self addSubview:overlay];
}
```

The code works fine. But my problem actually is, that the overlays are not on top of the imageViews, but have got an offset (from top and left). The top offset is the same for every view and the left offset increases per imageView (from left to right).

Screenshot with two overlays (the first and second imageView from left, bottom row):
[image]

Can anybody help me with this issue? Thanks a lot! Julian

Answer (score 0):

For everyone running into something like the same problem:

Using `self.bounds` instead of `self.frame` solved the issue.